# Using openssl on SoapServer. How to?

Tags: php, soap, openssl

Learning how to use openssl with wsdl. Problem is that I dont know how to use openssl on server side. I create SoapClient on client side:

```
$client = new SoapClient(   $uri,
                            array( 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                                'local_cert'=>"cert.pem",
                                "trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0,
                                "login" => 'user',
                                "password" => 'pass'
                                )
                        );
```

And I create SoapServer on server side:

```
$server = new SoapServer("http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/wsdl1/smsservice.wsdl.php");
$server->setClass("SoapSmsGateWay");
$server->handle();
```

I check login and password

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != 'user'|| $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != 'pass'
```

But I do not understand what I should to do on SoapServer to use openssl. Please, give me an example.